# Scrapy - Remove comma and whitespace from getall() results

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

would there be an effective way to directly remove commas from the yielded results via getall()?
As an example, the data I'm trying to retrieve is in this format:

```
<div>
Text 1
<br>
Text 2
<br>
Text 3
</div>
```

My current selector for this is:

```
response.xpath("//div//text()").getall()
```

Which does get the correct data but they come out as:

```
Text 1,
Text 2,
Text 3
```

instead of

```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
```

I understand that they get recognized as a list which is the reason for the commas but would there be a direct function to remove them without affecting the commas from the text itself?

Comment: I've not tested this but this may work. try adding strip(',') at the end. for eg, ..getall().strip(',') . This will strip off the trailing characters.

Comment: @Alexander is it because the object doesn't allow it? hmm then converting it to string will work.  str(contents).strip(',')

Comment: @Alexander Ah alright, sorry my bad. Add it to a loop ```for a in response.xpath("//div//text()").getall():``` and then strip them individually ```a.strip(',')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to leave the solution I used in case someone needs it:

```
tc = response.xpath("//div//text()").getall() #xpath selector
tcl = "".join(tc) #used to convert the list into a string
```

Comment: Doesn't this create the same issue as my other suggestion?  Didn't you say that all the commas inside the webpage text make excel separate them into different entries?

Comment: No, This approach actually fits really well with what I was looking for @Alexander. The commas are now removed from the end of each T&C number while being stored under one cell!

Comment: If this is the actual solution that worked for you then you should select it as the correct answer.

Comment: Noted and will do so once I'm allowed to about 20 hours from now haha. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your comments because I thought that the commas that were in the original page source were causing problems too